# asp.net core identity - Id column is nvarchar(450) - why?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

In the `dbo.AspNetUsers` table used by ASP.NET Core Identity the `Id` column is defined as `nvarchar(450)` as seen in the image below.

What is the reason for this, since Guids are stored in this column? If I am creating a foreign key referencing this `Id` column I don't really want to make the column unnecessarily large. Or is there a scenario when `Id` column of this size would be needed?

[image: ASP.NET Core Identity Users table]

Comment: 3 years later and no one knows why we continue to use a more expensive nvachar(450) over varchar(36) for our guids...

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why it's 450 in length, but it actually doesn't matter. The NVARCHAR type is dynamically sized, so the the number it's fed is actually a *max length*. It will only consume the amount of bytes necessary to store the data it's storing, regardless of the "length".

Comment: Thanks for this. I realize you can change the column type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x). Would you recommend changing the identifier to an `Int` instead? I don't suppose using string as primary key is a good idea from performance point of view (as well as size).

Comment: It actually doesn't matter that much. It's still an indexed column, so it's not really any less efficient to query against than an int PK. An int takes up less space, sure, but the extra few bytes won't likely matter weigh against the total size of your database. I usually use ints, but just because prefer to work with number "ids", not necessarily for performance or any other real reason.

Comment: It actually does matter! Creating the default migrations for 
the Identity tables will result in PKs that **CAN** in some situations exceed the 900 byte maximum key length.

Comment: @StefanBalan: The default PKs are GUIDs. They should never exceed 32-40 in length anyways. However, even if they were 450 in length, that *is* 900 bytes. Unicode is 2-bytes per char: 2 * 450 == 900.

Comment: It might affect creating composite PKs. Any composite key that is made with AspNetUsers.Id will generate `Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes.` message. I believe they made it 450 nvarchar as to max out PK size and hence prevent people from creating composite PKs that include Id column. But that is just a guess. As @ChrisPratt said by default AspNetUsers.Id are GUIDs, so there you have it.

Comment: Interesting. That seems like a plausible explanation, since creating a composite key with Identity's user would wreck all sorts of havoc.

Comment: They wouldn't make it `nvarchar(450)` to discourage people from creating indexes involving User's `Id`, since they do it themselves in `AspNetUserRoles.PK_AspNetUserRoles` which is 1800 bytes: `UserID`+`RoleId`

Comment: It should use ints, after that it should be a GUID column. Bizarre decision.

Comment: Not at all. They chose a column type that could hold anything. If it was an int, it wouldn't work for people that wanted to use guids. If it was a guid, it wouldn't work for people that wanted ints.

Comment: @niico I used to think like you but found out there a several amazing advantages of having your tables use guid PK. One such advantage is that you can merge several instances of the same database into one with no (theoretically) conflicts. Another really great advantage is that no one can guess the sequence of your guid fields (int PK-> 1,2,3,4,5...) making your application more secure from the start.

Comment: @TheLegendaryCopyCoder I used to think like you lol. I used GUID Id's everywhere. However Identity Id ISNT a GUID it's a varchar(450) with a GUID IN IT. The performance of GUID/varchar Ids are substantially worse than using int that's the problem.

Comment: @niico aha. Noted. I'm currently using varchar(36) PK populated with a C# generated guid. Yes, there will be a performance hit with a 32bit int PK vs 288bit+ varchar PK.

Comment: My take is regarding ef core and multilple underlying stores the string PK has wider support (Sqllite is an obvious outlier). Regarding the size it has always baffled me.